# React BaseTable rowSpan "flickering"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagridcell

### Problem

As seen in the interactive BaseTable API playground [here](https://autodesk.github.io/react-base-table/playground#ATDGHsDsGcBdgCYENZOAXmAbQFAhAN574gDWApgJ4BcwAjADTEkBEEANgK4C2kAtAAYWtFgCVwAd2ADgfYAGFw7aSyYkQbJT351hwMZOmyFS+qub5NXXnwBMeg1JlzFy3WvVXtfAMwPxTsauZh6sHN4ALP6GziZuLBYAvqHAROrAFDTAtika4TZCIgH0QaZCufr5OtFSdKXxFV429kWGdS6m7hZ5WjZ+rbX1Id2VvfxRAyUd8UkpaeqZtD6NVYI12UPlI03Vk7ZDXek7duv708NHq-36xWdxF56rEzeGd8G6sxbzJIvAEStjNaTHybcyXQG6YEHMGPQEtF5SEHnQ6w6z8a6OYBI+4osKA56Y7HvBIkZJfEa-ACsALRQIRf1BNO8kPpEWhTOa6zZyJheNpGOK3JxvMsTy50M+JG++F+ADYOfxCvTKYztqsWZiVTyFSdJlrhTqBYZ9cSdQTiibOiT8GSpRSqLQAOw6pWY2LBLbg2ka4ruq06+Fu9lqwFGwLakO080xCWkub2rIADhd6z9yk9qOZqeDXu8gd9OczfWzEdzNmj4eFkvw0rIDuAAE4U5M0yodT6Y6Wi-x852DZHvGGjF2+ZES1W4+T0r86AJm-TWxnRzYO5XTQPOS3C8v0eP12XxnurdXCAnaHRGBvFUf0yKet6bw8d7qF9vRaHH7j31HP9aQLaazPegcivOkg3OJdvyzLcRygzdX1g+9B1-M1fxPVIgLoZZQNdAsILvUYHxg-sDxfcCSO7XwUNAithwnG142nes6H+HDH0gpCV2o0jezXf1QKHVsv04w9iOJdDawyZjqTYsSygI45Vzo-dKN45T+NIwS3xEvhaKEv9gAA08mKyOh5VkhD7g4wjoMslTnzU-TDW4yi9NjG1iAAXQAbhwYgIBgeAqmgDBsCndRkFQABpetjms344oIgAnchoAASwALyQAAjdhyFoWAks4cgKlgNLYDykRXG0NsRgkNKEFgAALc9KQECSRkipAYqyRSCIS9VktSzKcsq4BCuK0ryrGlhqt4J98HqxqWvoNqOvSLqepEVZ7AqAa4SG9Ksty-LxqKkqRjKirTtmsZsgIpbmta9rJztDaUG62Krn6r6PwqFKjtG06Jou9IrpmubICxB6Gqe1aXoY8KSE236fz21Gx3+4bjrGkGpuuqq7qiCpHpWug1tJLzfJwAK4GAJLJAAZQAByQSAAElIAQcgAA9QvammoDphmJBZtmAEEkqS0KsGpHJlhySkfP8sZoCwEWxY5rnec8gA6DXWahzAAAoCHpyQABEPoYc2JE57m+cSABKDAAD4MJAWmlHIXX2HAABzY2Rft3mnZGEALDy+AkFAUB+YsAAzcBpeNqPsDS7WeZtnnPOAcAE9tzXJaS3XyEgQq0tS42nadyS0oL42Y7j9AW9tkOedr8PgCb0Ke4AamAHmu69vLfYD42WGDzPqFUNvM7D9JPaF72x8DyemcN4usAzh3PJnm2DYlqXt8zzyF8XlLYE4JKocPyAt53nWRkSYARhHn2-cDpvz5IHvMH7weSQLB4ESNTWm8ARaiDLtzFK0sTZmxFlbVAB9JDtxtqAcg7B2DQHQarQyLt0Du3mOAwuhtQrBXVhvNm7c9Z31NrbJBSAUF20zvg4g9dgBByoVDd2dAXbShIRgrB5DMHYMoaLQ2NCLAkLgJQPKoVJK6yUUI9gutmYM2ZtAXWsi8oVGyjHUg-sGacC5q4ZOM9maSBgblYqBEmrkDSv7JqsBaB32AAAKmAG1Ywl50hIHYI4yAjNMEJ1oAAcgTnlHmfA4BICSrAMJFQMrt3PCkRI0jRFqzvjQ0KUCY6wF1qAP2kByAAFE8rcDLrAY2KibZmx0eQNh-5iCX2vlDFR0AcDpJwLzSx8TEDkATkgTg7B4DVzdpw4gAAeAAKkDROaUebkAQNI1W6ACDBXScjD66yupbPwJA6B5BYHrMOdrWB+yQDgAAG7HOgKANmARFAmNgOs2w+yAD0rscBhyAA), the spanning rows flicker on/off when I start scrolling.

This is a known bug in the library, and there have been numerous issues posted regarding it:
https://github.com/Autodesk/react-base-table/issues/156

However, there does not seem to be any fix available. A comment on there states that this could be done, but I am not sure where in the code this would be placed:

```js
      const overscanBackward =
        !isScrolling || verticalScrollDirection === 'backward'
          ? Math.max(1, overscanCountResolved)
          : 1;
```

### What the table looks like

[image]

### Code

Same code as in the playground:

```
    const data = [
    {
      key: 1,
      "column-0": "Row 0 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 0 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      "column-0": "Row 1 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 1 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 1 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 1 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 1 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      "column-0": "Row 2 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 2 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 2 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 2 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 2 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 4,
      "column-0": "Row 3 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 3 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 3 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 3 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 3 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 5,
      "column-0": "Row 4 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 4 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 4 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 4 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 4 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 6,
      "column-0": "Row 5 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 5 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 5 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 5 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 5 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 7,
      "column-0": "Row 0 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 0 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 8,
      "column-0": "Row 0 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 0 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 9,
      "column-0": "Row 0 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 0 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 10,
      "column-0": "Row 0 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 0 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 11,
      "column-0": "Row 0 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 0 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 12,
      "column-0": "Row 0 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 0 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 13,
      "column-0": "Row 0 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 0 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 14,
      "column-0": "Row 0 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 0 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 15,
      "column-0": "Row 0 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 0 - Col 1"
    },
    {
      key: 16,
      "column-0": "Row 0 - Col 0",
      "column-1": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-2": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-3": "Row 0 - Col 1",
      "column-4": "Row 0 - Col 1"
    }
  ];

  const columns = [
    {
      dataKey: "column-0",
      key: "column-0",
      resizable: true,
      title: "Column 0",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      dataKey: "column-1",
      key: "column-1",
      resizable: true,
      title: "Column 1",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      dataKey: "column-2",
      key: "column-2",
      resizable: true,
      title: "Column 2",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      dataKey: "column-3",
      key: "column-3",
      resizable: true,
      title: "Column 3",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      dataKey: "column-4",
      key: "column-4",
      resizable: true,
      title: "Column 4",
      width: 150
    }
  ];

const rowSpanIndex = 0

const rowSpanArr = [5,2,3,2,5];
  columns[rowSpanIndex].rowSpan = ({ rowData, rowIndex }) => {
  console.log(rowIndex)
        
    let acc = 0
    for (let [index, x] of rowSpanArr.entries()){
      if (acc === rowIndex){
        acc = acc + x
        console.log("rowIndex:", rowIndex)
        console.log("rowSpanArr[index]:", rowSpanArr[index])
        return rowSpanArr[index]
      } 
      console.log(acc)
      acc = acc + x
    }
    
 };

const rowRenderer = ({ rowData, rowIndex, cells, columns }) => {
  const rowSpan = columns[rowSpanIndex].rowSpan({ rowData, rowIndex })
  if (rowSpan > 1) {
    const cell = cells[rowSpanIndex]
    const style = {
      ...cell.props.style,
      backgroundColor:"powderblue",
      height: rowSpan * 50 - 1,
      alignSelf: 'flex-start',
      zIndex: 1,
    }
    cells[rowSpanIndex] = React.cloneElement(cell, { style })
  }
  return cells
}

export default () => (
  <Table
    fixed
    columns={columns}
    data={data}
    rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
    overscanRowCount={2}
  />
)
```

Does anyone have any idea of what a temporary fix would look like? I really need this feature..

Comment: Hello! Well the comment on GitHub was referring to this: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window/blob/d80bef25fe706d0c73fc801674c086f681811190/src/createGridComponent.js#L714 but seems to be fixed yet, have you the last version of this package? The comment, btw, was referring to a bug in a dependency of your package.

Comment: I have the latest version yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution has been found! The code underneath is for a little more complex example, but I think the procedure can be used.

```
columns[rowSpanIndex].rowSpan = ({ rowIndex }) => {
    let acc = 0;
    for (let [index, x] of rowSpanArr.entries()) {
      if (acc === rowIndex) {
        acc = acc + x;

        return rowSpanArr[index];
      }

      acc = acc + x;
    }
  };
```

```
const rowRenderer = ({ rowData, rowIndex, cells, columns }) => {
    // for the rows which should not span across any other rows
    const rowSpan = columns[rowSpanIndex].rowSpan({ rowData, rowIndex });
    if (rowSpan === undefined) {
      const cell = cells[rowSpanIndex];
      let style = {
        ...cell.props.style,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        color: "white",
        alignSelf: "flex-start",
        zIndex: 3
      };

      cells[rowSpanIndex] = React.cloneElement(cell, { style });
    }
    if (rowSpan > 1) {
    // for the spanning rows
      const cell = cells[rowSpanIndex];
      const style = {
        ...cell.props.style,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        height: rowSpan * 48 - 1,
        alignSelf: "flex-start",
        zIndex: 1
      };
      cells[rowSpanIndex] = React.cloneElement(cell, { style });
    }
```

Along with the CSS

```
.BaseTable__row-cell{
  align-items: flex-start;
  }
```